# Show $f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation at $z=0$ but $f$ is not differentiable at $z=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> $$f(z)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0 &\text{if}& {\bf Re\,}z\,{\bf Im\,}z=0,\\
> 1 &\text{if}& {\bf Re\,}z\,{\bf Im\,}z\neq0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   show that $f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equation at $z=0$ but $f$ is not differentiable at $z=0$.

how to solve this problem we have to show cauchy-rimann equation means

$u_x=v_y$ and $v_x=-u_y$

but how to find this !

Comment: @MyGlasses...thank you sir

Comment: What are $u$ and $v$ here?

Comment: @MyGlasses..real and imaginary parts of z

Comment: Here $v=0$ and $$u(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if}& xy=0,\\
1 &\text{if}& xy\neq0.
\end{cases}
$$ right?

Comment: @MyGlasses..yes

Comment: Can you find $v_x$ and $v_y$?

Comment: @MyGlasses..BOTH ARE O

Comment: and $u_x$, $u_y$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65157/discussion-between-suresh-and-myglasses).

Comment: @MyGlasses.. i am confusing about ux and uy

Comment: $$u_x=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{1-1}{h}=0$$
when $xy\neq0$

Comment: @MyGlasses..but given $xy\neq0$

Comment: and also $u_x=0$ when $xy=0$.

Comment: @MyGlasses..lly uy =0 ane hence  f is cauchy equation now how to prove  f is not differentiable

Comment: $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: @MyGlasses is we check $\frac{f(z)-f(o)}{z-0}$ for differentiability

Comment: @MyGlasses....yes are right f is not continuous at z=0 ..thank you so much for your help

Comment: you are welcome.